# Why is gulp trying to import scss libraries which are removed from my project?

Tags: npm, sass, gulp

I'm working on a website that has gulp set up to compile scss and launch a dev server. I didn't set up the project and the person who did is unavailable to ask directly.

It worked fine previously but now when I run the gulp command in the terminal, it gives me this error:

```
Error in plugin "sass"
Message:
    sass/projectName.styles.scss
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: breakpoint.
        on line 4 of sass/projectName.styles.scss
>> @import "breakpoint";
```

So it seems the fairly obvious, however my attempts to fix it don't seem to make any difference.

I have changed the includedPaths to point to the breakpoint module in my node_modules folder, but what really confuses me is that even if I comment out the "@import breakpoint" line in projectName.styles.scss, it still gives me the same error message. Which makes me think gulp not reading the changes to my gulpfile, but I'm not sure why.

I'm assuming it's something simple, but as far as I'm aware gulp doesn't have a cache or need to be cleaned after changes to the gulpfile, so again, I'm not sure why it's doing this.

Here's the include paths section of my gulp file.

```
var sass_config = {
  importer: importer,
  includePaths: [
    'node_modules/breakpoint-sass/stylesheets/',
    'node_modules/singularitygs/stylesheets/',
    'node_modules/compass-mixins/lib/',
  ]
};
```

Any insight or ideas on what I can try would be helpful. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I figured out the problem and thought I'd answer my own question for prosperity.

What happened was, earlier I had deleted the project repo while I still had the project open in Sublime. I did not close the project in Sublime (though I did close Sublime itself, there is a slight difference) and cloned the repo again.

When I went to started working on it today, I continued in the window which was open in Sublime.

I'm not an expert in how the text editor works but I guess there was a copy or reference to the deleted project repo files in memory or something, so the files I was editing, i.e gulpfile.js, weren't actually the files I was interacting with in the terminal using gulp.

I figured it out when I did `git status` and the files I was editing were unchanged. Closing the project window and opening the project in Sublime again solved my problem.

So a bit of a silly mistake on my part, but at least we learned something ae!